# Where is the BurpSuite CA HTTPS certificate located?

Tags: burp-suite

Following this question -> [Why are HTTPS requests blocked by Firefox when using ZAP proxy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147250/why-are-https-requests-blocked-by-firefox-when-using-zap-proxy/147251#147251)

I was looking in Burp Suite where I could generate its CA for Firefox. I could not see it. I went to Burp website -> https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783087-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-firefox but they show a url `http://burp` which is not working on my browser.

Where can I generate Burp's certificate?

Comment: If you proxy Firefox through burp, you should be able to get to the http:\\burp screen - if not, it suggests that the proxy configuration isn't correct. Make sure that you're seeing requests in burp if you visit http based sites, and that you don't have intercept enabled holding the browser up.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah I was not redirecting traffing through Burp. Thank you.i works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to get the CA cert -

1) ***Make sure your browser is pointing to the Burp proxy Interface Url and Port*** and navigate to `http://burp` and click on "CA Certificate" on the top right. In your question, you had used `\\` instead of `//`

2) On Burp, go to Proxy tab > Options Tab > 'Import/Export CA Certificate' Button in the "Proxy Listeners" section.

Load the CA cert on to the trusted CA certs store in the browser.......

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://burp . Click on CA certificate and a cacert.dir file will be downloaded.

Now go to `-> preferences -> advanced -> certificate -> view certificate -> import` and select that cacert.dir file and click open.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too and solved it by:

1. Setup your browser to proxy through burp.
2. Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8080 or whatever port you are using.
3. Download the certificate.